# How to cross compile libxml2 with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc compiler. How to cross compile using third party libraries?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, libxml2

when I tried to cross compile I am getting an error

/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31:26: fatal error: unicode/ucnv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: I guess you need `libicu-dev` package.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -o test test.c -L/path/to/unicode/directory -lucnv.h`

Comment: This only shows how to compile and link a single C file. It doesn't help at all with building libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

In recent releases of libxml2, the configure script tries to detect ICU using pkg-config. Depending on your setup, this could result in false positives when cross-compiling (see [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html) for details). I'd suggest to disable ICU support by passing `--without-icu` to configure. ICU is a huge library and libxml2 only uses it to convert between character sets. It also supports libiconv which is much smaller.